# cqlsh: how to skip first few rows in resultset

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh

How can I skip first few rows in the resultset in cqlsh? I know I can iterate the resultset and ignore first few rows, but I am looking to do it in the query itself.

Following queries work in SQL, but what is their equivalent in cqlsh

```
      SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10, 50
      SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

I looked up QueryBuilder (and related classes in DataStax) and didnot find anything there. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Results pagination in Cassandra (CQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757287/results-pagination-in-cassandra-cql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, CQL does not currently include support for a starting offset.  The LIMIT clause only controls an upper bound and not a starting offset.

See the documentation [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html).

Probably your best bet would be to use tail and run cqlsh from bash like this:

```
cqlsh -e "SELECT ... LIMIT 10;" | tail -n+9
```

The value of 9 would skip the first 5 lines since there is a header for the column names you need to skip also.

If you are writing in java then of course you'd have other programmatic options.